# Estrutura de arquivos e deployment de aplicações JSF com JBoss EAP no Debian 8

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, linux

Gostaria de saber se há como configurar o JBoss EAP para fazer deploy de aplicações Java (JSF, Hibernate, PrimeFaces, Maven) na pasta `/var/www/`.

A estrutura da pasta `/var/www` é a seguinte:

```
/var/www
    /php
    /java
        /appjsf1.war
        /appjsf2.war
    /python
```

O JBoss está instalado em `/opt/jboss-eap-6/` e as aplicações Java rodam em `/opt/jboss-eap-6/server/default/deploy` só que eu não quero que as aplicações fiquem dentro da pasta do servidor de aplicação.

Minha dúvida vem da insatisfação com a atual estrutura dos arquivos que roda dentro da pasta do servidor de aplicação e também por curiosidade. Já que existem muitos sistemas distribuídos para dar escalabilidade aos grandes projetos de software e o JBoss é usado em muitos deles, eu pense que eu pudesse separar o repositório de códigos das minhas aplicações do servidor JBoss.

Aproveitando, e se eu quiser rodar o JBoss num servidor e deixar meus códigos em outro servidor distinto, é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de pesquisar bastante encontrei a forma certa de perguntar e é esta:

**Como alterar a pasta de deployment default do JBoss?**

As respostas surgiram naturalmente:

- [How to change JBoss eap 6.1 deployment
  folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927400/how-to-change-jboss-eap-6-1-deployment-folder)
- [Deploying a war outside of a deploy directory in
  jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879275/deploying-a-war-outside-of-a-deploy-directory-in-jboss)

A principal fonte é a da própria RedHat ("dona" do JBoss EAP):

- [Chapter 7. Deploying
  Applications](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications)